# access nested data in json

Tags: python, json, azure

I want to retrieve all the IP address range from Azure cloud from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=41653)
The data after conversion in json is in the following format:

```
{
  "AzurePublicIpAddresses": {
    "Region": [
      {
        ...
        "IpRange": [
          {
            "_Subnet": "40.69.96.0/19"
          },
          {
            "_Subnet": "40.86.192.0/18"
          }
        ],
        "_Name": "canadaeast"
      },
      {
        "IpRange": [
          {
            "_Subnet": "13.71.160.0/19"
          },
          {
            "_Subnet": "13.88.224.0/19"
          },
          {
            "_Subnet": "40.85.192.0/18"
          }
        ],
        "_Name": "canadacentral"
      }
    ],
    "_xmlns:xsd": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
    "_xmlns:xsi": "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  }
}
```

I am unable to access IP ranges? through this code?

```
with open('AZURE_IP.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

list_IPCIDR = []
for i in data["AzurePublicIpAddresses"]:
    for ii in i["Region"]:
        for j in ii["IpRange"]:
            list_IPCIDR.append(i["_Subnet"])

sys.stdout=open("test2.txt","w")
```

Comment: Not a good idea to link to a hosting site such as the one you linked to. Especially since the content will shortly expire, damaging this question.

Comment: ohh, but it was such a big file, i thought not to paste here

Comment: I'm not suggesting pasting a huge file here. But you could trivially include a snippet of your converted JSON. And... by linking to a huge file, you're essentially forcing anyone wishing to answer this question to download that file.

Comment: sorry, removed that file & pasted a sample done

Comment: Do you receive an error or do you see nothing?

Comment: yes it is   for ii in i["Region"]:
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data["AzurePublicIpAddresses"]` is a `dict`. Iterating directly over a `dict` just gives you the the keys of that `dict`.

So

```
for i in data["AzurePublicIpAddresses"]:
    print(i)
```

will print

```
Region
_xmlns:xsd
_xmlns:xsi
```

in some order.

You can get the Subnet IP ranges like this:

```
list_IPCIDR = []
for ipr in data["AzurePublicIpAddresses"]["Region"]:
    for d in ipr["IpRange"]:
        list_IPCIDR.append(d["_Subnet"])

print(list_IPCIDR)
```

**output**

```
['40.69.96.0/19', '40.86.192.0/18', '13.71.160.0/19', '13.88.224.0/19', '40.85.192.0/18']
```

This works because `data["AzurePublicIpAddresses"]["Region"]` is a list of `dict`s. Each of those `dict` (that are temporarily bound to the name `ipr`) contains a list of `dict`s associated with the "IpRange" key, so we need to iterate over those lists in the inner loop, and then extract the subnet strings from those inner `dict`s.

If you like you can do this in a list comprehension, butI advise splitting it up over several lines, eg:

```
list_IPCIDR = [d["_Subnet"] 
    for ipr in data["AzurePublicIpAddresses"]["Region"] 
        for d in ipr["IpRange"]]
```

---

It's often desirable to iterate over the (key, value) pairs of a `dict`. You can do that using the `.items` method (or `.iteritems` in Python 2). Eg,

```
list_IPCIDR = []
for key, val in data["AzurePublicIpAddresses"].items():
    if key == "Region":
        for dct in val:
            for s in dct["IpRange"]:
                list_IPCIDR.append(s["_Subnet"])
```

Answer (score 0):

`AzurePublicIpAddresses` is a dictionary, so:

```
for i in data["AzurePublicIpAddresses"]:
```

Iterates through the keys (which are strings, in this case). I.e. you're trying to do "Region"["Region"], which is string slicing. Try something more like:

```
for i in data["AzurePublicIpAddresses"]:
    for ii in data["Azure..."][i]:
        # Use ii as it is the contents of the 'Region' attribute
        if type(ii) == list: # Sometimes ii is a string, like at the end of your data.
            list_IPCIDR.append(ii["IpRange"]["_Subnet"])
```

Comment: u mean this list_IPCIDR.append(ii["IpRange"]["_Subnet"])?

Comment: Yes, that snippet looks like it will do what you ask (appending each `_Subnet` into the list). Code above edited to be complete.